# Simple ajax jQuery call doesn't return me any html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loading

He guys i am having this problem with loading a page through jQuery ajax. 
This is my first time trying to do something with jQuery and ajax calls.
However a simple load doesn't show me anything also i don't know how to show all the error's it generates if it generates error's.

Any what i want is to retrieve the pages html data, would appreciate it if somebody can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using jQuery 1.10.2

This is the code I am trying to use.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
   loadPage();
});

function loadPage(){
var obj = {};
obj.test=true;
obj.something=true;

     $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'http://www.w3.org/',
        data:obj,
        success:onLoadComplete,
        error:onError
     });
};

function onError(){
    console.log($(this));
}

function onLoadComplete(pdata, pstatus, pxhr){
   console.log("respons: " + pdata);
   console.log("text status: " + pstatus);
   console.log("xhr: " + pxhr);
}
```

Comment: it looks like a violation of [Same Origin Policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy)

Comment: try printing pdata.responseText in onLoadComplete method

Comment: Is your `onLoadComplete` function firing? I believe you have missed a parameter in your `onError` function also. ( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown ) - Found at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ under the `Error` item in settings.

Comment: @ArunPJohny could be not sure how can I make sure this isn't the problem? And is this the way to fix it? "the HTML <script> element can execute content retrieved from foreign origins"

Comment: @Nunners I don't really understand what I missed can I access those params from by doing $(this).jqXHR for example? Or isn't that what you ment?

Comment: if you look at the browser console it should say `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.w3.org/. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. ` see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LUfXS/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny a yes now I See. Is there a way to do this anyway connect to a web page and read it or is there nothing you can do about it?